# I'm supposed to be writing a program but no matter what i try to fix it, like delete something and then

Tags: java

it tells me it needs it, It wont fix. where exactly am i going wrong?

What I have so far is this:

```
public class DistanceTraveled {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int speed = 0,
        hours = 0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the speed: ");
    speed = keyboard.nextInt();

    while(speed < 0){
        System.out.print("Enter the speed: ");
        speed = keyboard.nextInt();
}

System.out.print("Enter the amount of hours traveled: ");
hours = keyboard.nextInt();

   while(hours < 1){
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of hours traveled (MPH): ");
    hours = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

   System.out.println("Hours" + " Distance Traveled");
   System.out.println("------------------------------------");

int hr = 1;

while(hours >= 1){
    System.out.println(" " + hr + " " + hr * speed + " MPH");
    hr++;
    hours--;
    }
}
}
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
symbol  : class Scanner
location: class DistanceTraveled
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ^
DistanceTraveled.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Scanner
location: class DistanceTraveled
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                               ^
```

Comment: Did you add your imports?

Comment: Please change your question title to describe the problem. It is currently useless.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to import Scanner. Put this at the top of your file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

More generally, you shouldn't just "delete something" and hope for the best. That's called shotgun debugging, and it will only lead to worse headaches. Instead, take the time to google the error and understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code, the only compiler error seem to be missing an import

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Or, you can use the full name in your code and then you don't need the `import` -

```
java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```